# assignment of c short to Ada short_integer

Tags: c, type-conversion, ada

I am missing something basic on my ideas about how Ada and types.  All I want to do is something like this:

```
    procedure Example(  rec_len : in  interfaces.c.short )  is

        shortLen      : Short_integer   := 0;
        recLen        : integer := 0;

    begin -- example

         shortLen := rec_len;   -- and
         recLen   := shortLen;

         Text_IO.Put_Line( "rec length = "& Integer'IMAGE( recLen ));

    end example;
```

In other words jut get the integer value from the `C` language `short` type.

in the `i-c.ads` the definition for `short` is the same --

```
     type short is new Short_Integer;
```

i can't find a reference or example that shows the syntatic sugar needed to do that simple operation.

On the line: `shortLen := rec_len`, the GNAT compiler says "expected type Standard.Short_Integer", which is of course.  However, I haven't found a suitable "to_Short() type call that works.  I realise it is a basic question, I still think it ought to be something I can find in a document someplace(*easily*???).  Thanks in advance for your know-how.

Comment: I presume you mean `Interfaces.C`, not `Interface.C`. Please copy-and-paste your actual code into the question.

Did you really mean for your `Example` procedure to have a parameter `rec_len` of type `Interfaces.C.Short` and a local variable `recLen` of type `Integer`?

Comment: Thanks yes I've corrected that.  Yes that is the actual code, it has been trimmed down to just print the integer value of the `short` value.

Comment: For future reference, you should copy-and-paste your code (that would have avoided the `interface` vs. `interfaces` typo), and the code in the question should be compilable, not just a fragment. Read this: [mcve].

Comment: You might find the [Wikibooks section on the Ada type system](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System) useful.

Comment: @SimonWright ... yes I checked there first I think, or second.  NO examples about short_integer -- You see `short` (as explained by Keith) isn't the same and kept giving compile errors.  As an occassional Ada wader, I find a lot of assumed knowledge in these reference sources (_ho hum_).

Comment: That was actually a response to your "I am missing something basic on my ideas about how Ada and types"

Answer (score 5):

Ada (unlike C) doesn't let you assign a value of one numeric type to a variable of another numeric type without an explicit conversion.

This should work:

```
shortLen := Short_Integer(rec_len);
recLen := Integer(shortLen);
```

This declaration:

```
type short is new Short_Integer;
```

doesn't make `short` an alias for `Short_Integer` (as `typedef` does in C). It makes `short` a new and distinct type derived from `Short_Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination too, yes I was thinking a `typedef` kind of thing.  Also I had thought I'd used `integer( rec_len )` earlier -- That is a big blue, that one.

Comment: As a complement, with `subtype short is Short_Integer;`, then you would have an alias type.